# watchdog trigger duplicated/repeated events when copy

Tags: python-watchdog

I have a Samba Shared folder in my linux (CentOS 6.7) and I'm Trying to copy a file from windows to mapped path: Y:/callcenter (samba shared), when I copy a jar file to this folder watchdog repeats the event copy alot of time...

`on_created(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileCreatedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)
on_modified(self=<watchdog.tricks.LoggerTrick object at 0x162ec10>, event=<FileModifiedEvent: src_path='./333.jar'>)`

and till finish...

here's my command

`watchmedo log --patterns="*.jar" --ignore-directories --recursive`

does anyone knows a solution?